# What is Synchronous and asynchronous in android?

Tags: android

I want to know the definition and meaning of word Synchronous and Asynchronous.Can any one explain me these topics I will be really appreciate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Synchronous : will run in the same thread.

Asynchronous: will run in a different thread.

Comment: Thanks Augusto ..............

Comment: Please don't post link only answers to other Stack Overflow questions. Instead, vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, *tailor the answer to this specific question.*